# Do search engines understand multiple rel values?

Tags: html, search-engines

I need to have hyperlinks on my page that will look something like:

```
<a href="/someurl" rel="prettyPhoto[main] nofollow">Link</a>
```

So basically the `rel` attribute has two values.

I know it is valid HTML (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878657/multiple-values-for-rel-attribute), but my question is specifically about whether search engines will understand it.

I would hate it when SE's index stupid json strings on my site :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure Google recognise author and nofollow when used together. Perhaps someone can expand on this if they know more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they can still read it. See example at [this link](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=96569)

> With **rel="me nofollow"**, Google will continue to treat the
>   **rel="nofollow"** as expected for search purposes, such as not
>   transferring PageRank.

Comment: Looks to be the case indeed. Although they kinda say specifically with `me`. But I think you're right and SE's will just use all the values of the attribute.